# Switch Game Center accounts confirm button won't pop up

Tags: technical-issues, ios, clash-of-clans, game-center

I have multiple accounts on CoC and I used to be able to switch between 2 of the accounts I have.
 I was on one, and was trying to get on the other. When I switched Game Centers I switched back to CoC, but as I got in, the confirm button didn't appear.

Please help me. The CONFIRM button won't pop up but it signs me into Game Center just fine...
Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I, personally, have never had this problem. Your problem may be that the account that you are trying to add may have not correctly linked to the game center account. The account that you are trying to link may be lost forever. If you think that this may be your problem, you should try to contact [Supercell](https://gamesupport.supercell.net/hc/en-us/articles/202564123-Save-your-village-with-Game-Center) to see if you can find your account again.